# How To Detect Quick Settings Tile Settings Icon Click Listen Event?

Tags: android, android-studio, events, listener, settings

[i want to listen the settings  icon click event using broadcast receiver but could not do this, how can i achieve this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbBqI.jpg)

Comment: Are you creating a modified version of the Android OS?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried into your question. It will increase the chances of you receiving help from others and reduce the changes of having your question flagged and removed.

Comment: @CommonsWare No, Bro......actually i work in an MDM application. In this application for android 12 version when open any application from my mdm application and user pull down notification panel and access the settings system application and user can exit the mdm from default home app selection. for this reason i want to prevent this could you please any advice to prevent this